# How to download refrences part of emails using java?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I am trying to download the email using imap java ..I have downloaded most of the part of email but don't know how to download references part of email?Can someone provide help about which function is used to do that?any links to some page would be helpful.Thanks

```
References: <CALdDwZ=PQDu2eS1R2ONsrHJDgHDeZuNCUfEsfRqC3efzZfMaqg@mail.gmail.com>
    <CAAD0KRhD7w1qdRiTG6U00ShroE1R00h7F73_AQ4yRnDE7jm6HA@mail.gmail.com>
    <CALdDwZm2np83PmjrHY1jO54+6-dNKaM7+oxjaUHE_rUitMffrA@mail.gmail.com>
    <CAAD0KRg2TJt0Y4oo-CsOCexrmat6kHakuFZSm_AvTDuSXjiTTw@mail.gmail.com>
    <CAAD0KRhXUUwNjcAhc+4h-ftiJFW7q0y9gmDRGZ0khzyzWUDxbQ@mail.gmail.com>
    <CAAD0KRgp6nhupkQhu2LWe6mXGuvK35XFdZLUUjfC4uGvsOZtcQ@mail.gmail.com>
    <CAAD0KRhXaJ5FAuOxR760HBzgaD-_JyXoVAymeQf+nQdCawEgGA@mail.gmail.com>
```

These are message Id's of all the mails which took part in a conversation..Usually this is a part of an email.so I want to download it?

Answer (score 0):

For downloading the References part of the email we need to use **getHeader()** function of Imap java ..This is the code :

```
    if( msg.getHeader("References")!=null)
{
            String[] headers = msg.getHeader("References");
                System.out.println("headers");
                for(int ab=0;ab<headers.length;ab++)
               System.out.println(headers[ab]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The references are Message-IDs.  There's no way to directly access a message given the Message-ID.  You can use the Folder.search method to search for messages with the given Message-ID in the specified folder, but there's no way to know what folder the message might have been moved to, nor is there any guarantee that the current user ever saw the referenced message.